# How to List shared folder emails in DRIVE with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 1000 folders shared with different users on the drive, how can I make a list in GAS, with the emails of the people with whom I shared them?

Answer (score 1):

You must enable Advanced Drive API

```
function getSharedDrivesMembersList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//sheet name
  sh.clearContents();
  const dObj=JSON.parse(Drive.Drives.list({"supportsAllDrives":true}));//get shared drive ids
  //let oA=[];//debug
  let vs=[['Drive Name','Drive id','Name','Email','Domain','Type','Role']];//spreadsheet header row
  dObj.items.forEach(d => {
    mObj=JSON.parse(Drive.Permissions.list(d.id,{"supportsAllDrives":true}));//get permissions for each drive
    mObj.items.forEach(item =>{
      //oA.push({DriveName: d.name, driveId: d.id,name: item.name,email: item.emailAddress, domain: item.domain, type:item.type, role:item.role});//debug
      vs.push([d.name,d.id,item.name,item.emailAddress,item.domain,item.type,item.role])
    });
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));//debug
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//load spreadsheet
}
```

Redacted Sheet Data:

| Drive Name | Drive id | Name | Email | Domain | Type | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| Open | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 App | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 Share | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| QTRX2 Share | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |
| Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | Redacted | user | organizer |

The first loop provides this data:

```
{"items":[{"kind":"drive#drive","id":"","name":""},
```

The second loop provides this data:

```
{"kind":"drive#permissionList","items":[
{"name":"","deleted":false,"id":"","selfLink":"","etag":"","domain":"","type":"","kind":"drive#permission","role":"","permissionDetails":[{"role":"","inherited":false,"permissionType":""}],
"teamDrivePermissionDetails":[{"inherited":false,"teamDrivePermissionType":"","role":""}],
  "emailAddress":""},
```

[Google Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference)